# How can I chose a variables file basis a variable value in ansible while generating files from templates

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I am using ansible templates to generate config files. The issue is I ended up with a lot of conditional statements in my template that I want to get rid of by picking the right variables file using a simple condition.

How can I achieve this.. For example:
Instead of -

```
if os is defined in input variable file and os == 'centos'
 if osver =7 
  username='centos7' 
  password='centos7passwd'
 else if sver =8
  username='centos8' 
  password='centos8passwd'
else if os is defined in input variable file and os == 'ubuntu'
username='ubuntu' 
password='ubuntupasswd'
endif
```

and many such more, I would rather keep the template cleaner with just picking up the right variables file say

```
if os is defined in input variable file and os == 'centos7' pick variables from file centos7_var.yaml
else if os == 'centos8' pick variables from file centos8_var.yaml
else if os == 'ubuntu' pick variables from file centos8_var.yaml
and generate the configuration from template
```

Is it something fundamentally wrong that I am doing here. Not an expert at ansible.

Comment: FWIW, see [al_include_os_vars_path.yml](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-lib/blob/master/tasks/al_include_os_vars_path.yml)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ansible_facts the nested variable to use in your conditions

Check this page they have some useful examples I think it could help you deal with this issue "Discovering variables: facts and magic variables — Ansible Documentation" https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html